# Symfony 3 The autoloader expected class

Tags: php, symfony

I´m new on symfony.
I´m getting this error when I try to run

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities LoginBundle:Users
```

> The autoloader expected class "LoginBundle\Entity\Users" to be defined
>   in file ... The file was found but the class was not in it, the class
>   name or namespace probably has a typo.

My entity is:

```
<?
// src/LoginBundle/Entity/Users.php
namespace LoginBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="mail", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $mail;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $lastname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $password;

    public function getMail()
    {
        return $this->mail;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getLastname()
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setMail($data)
    {
        $this->mail = $data;
        return;
    }

    public function setName($data)
    {
        $this->name = $data;
        return;
    }

    public function setLastname($data)
    {
        $this->lastname = $data;
        return;
    }

    public function setPassword($data)
    {
        $this->password = $data;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried to delete symfony cache?

Comment: change php open tag to <?php please not only <?

Comment: Hi @AlessandroMinoccheri how can I delete cache? and why I need to add the php to <? ? about that I change it and now I get another error: [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException] An exception occured in driver: could not find driver

Comment: To clear the cache easily remove the directory var/cache/dev or prod depends on your environment. This is a new error of connection. 
I make an answer because this problem is solved with <?php open tag ok?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri ok but why do I need to opne tag like that, is a symfony require?

Comment: I have clarified It inside my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php open tag is wrong, because it's a server configuration about `short_open_tag`

See the [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php):

try to change

```
<?
```

to

```
<?php
```